# Should we start linking to the Android 3.0 library now for our apps?

Tags: android

I'm trying to enable hardware acceleration in my app as per the android dev blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html

It says to just add:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

to my manifest. In order to do that, are we supposed to use the Android 3.0 library for compilation? Right now I've been using the Android 2.3.3 library. My app is really designed for a phone form, not tablet. Is it ok to use the Android 3.0 library, or is that supposed to be specifically for tablet applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is okay, BUT:

- Always compile against your minSdkVersion once shortly before you release your app to make sure you didn't accidentally use an API that's only available in a higher SDK, or else you'll get reports of Force Closes.
- Using a higher target version will make the builder assume that you did everything according to the specs of the new SDK. If you look at the guidelines for icons, for example, you'll see that those are very different for 2.3 and then for 3.0.

Android uses a compatibility mode when a lower target version is running on a newer phone. For example, Android 1.5 and below couldn't support different densities or resolutions, so an app compiled for 1.5 would use a compatibility mode on a 1.6+ phone.

Comment: Good advice here. If you're really careful you can use newer APIs when you detect you're running on a new enough device (see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html for an example of how) which will break your suggestion for testing.

Comment: I am trying to figure this out as well. In your first bullet you mention to try compiling with Android 2.3.3 Library. But that will not compile, the manifest will give an error for the line android:hardwareAccelerated="true" unless you use Android 3.0 or later. So I am confused by this. Can we use manifest features from a later SDK safely but just not actual code?

Comment: @metalideath: Correct. You can also use code features from a higher SDK, provided that you never access the *class* that contains it when run from a lower-version SDK.